# Installed window builder in eclipse 2019-12 but unable to find it

Tags: java, eclipse, windowbuilder

I have installed window builder in eclipse 2019-12 but unable to find it whenever i try to open a file with open with or whenever i try to create new project from file wizard. So how can i launch window builder in eclipse 2019-12 after installation?

please find the screenshot of Help > About Eclipse IDE: Installation Details [image]

Comment: That doesn't sound like you installed WindowBuilder successfully. Check _Help > About Eclipse IDE: Installation Details_ if you really have installed it. But as first thing, you should update your pretty old Eclipse.

Comment: Open what kind of file?

Comment: Swing files, but i can not find option of opening the file with window builder.

Comment: @howlger to what version i should update eclipse

Comment: Latest version of Eclipse is 2022-06. Next version is due to be released next month, i.e. September 2022. You can download latest Eclipse from here: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/ And you can download WindowBuilder from here: https://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/download.php I suggest that you remove your current Eclipse installation and install the latest version. After you install the latest version, then install the latest WindowBuilder. Note that Eclipse 2022-06 comes with JDK 17 as part of the distribution.